# Playing playlist of videos in background on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, autoplay

Due to [a fairly recent update](http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-no-longer-autoplay-video-background-tabs/), Chrome no longer will autoplay media content such as video if it tries to start in a tab or window which does not have focus.

There are a few sites, including my own - which rely on switching then playing videos in the background as a music player. This has been broken by Chrome, with their idea being that it prevents annoying videos from playing.

I'm reluctant to even consider building a chrome extension to circumvent this (if that would even work), but would like to hear how if possible. Is there any way to get around this annoying issue?

edit: [according to this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3pbebj/as_of_chrome_460249071_you_can_no_longer_play/) it may not be Chrome, but YouTube's chrome specific implementation...

edit2: [this Chrome issue](https://codereview.chromium.org/1292433002/) states that “Once a tab / RenderFrame has ever played media before, it’s allowed to continue to autoplay/autoload indefinitely; this is to support playlist type applications.” - Perhaps if somehow a 'RenderFrame' contains all future media which is also loaded by AJAX this will work... whatever a render frame is (Since as noted in the comments, a page reload/change does not count as the user having allowed autoplay.)

Comment: annoying for you... blessed silence for everyone else.

Comment: @MarcB everyone is a lot of people. Not everyone is looking for silence

Comment: Also, I understand the issue it's trying to solve. But seriously, what about the websites out there that act as music players? This is my question

Comment: start the music in the main/focused tab, then put a "feel free to switch elsewhere" message in there?

Comment: @MarcB my site changes page to access a new video/'song' and autoplays (if user-enabled). I guess it just means that the server-side approach of doing things is now not possible (in Chrome) (also, my site allows different sources besides youtube to be embedded so just using the JavaScript player will not suffice.)